Is Expo supports react-native-encrypted-storage? or How to store sensitive data (like token) in react native that built with expo?
ERROR  Error: RNEncryptedStorage is undefined, js engine: hermes
at ContextNavigator (http://192.168.0.105:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo-router%5Centry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:148715:24)
....
...
..
.
It gives an error when I try to execute this:
const token = await EncryptedStorage.getItem("user-token");
await EncryptedStorage.removeItem("user-token");


As you're using Expo, I recommend using SecureStore https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/
Usage overview:
Set a value
await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);

Get a value
const result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);


Expo supports also AsyncStorage https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/async-storage/
I recommend using it.
To store data use this
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', jsonValue)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }

To retrieve data instead use this:
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}

Use this as a base, as this two functions retrieve objects. If you only want to store a single string or value those are not ok.
